# querying nested JSON in mongodb using find

Tags: mongodb

My JSON is:

```
db.col.insert([

    {
        "1":[
            {
                "a":"1",
                "b":"2",
                "v":"12"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2":[
            {
                "a":"12",
                "v":"451"
            }
        ]
    }])
```

when I query using

db.col.find("1")

It is returning both the rows instead of the condition. how can i select just one row here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the data by checking if the given field exists using $exists keyword as follows :

```
db.col.find({1 : {$exists:true}})
```